# How to fill multiple cell one after another in one column refer to adjacent cell

Tags: excel, vba

In the table below you will see values so you can easily understand what I am asking for!
[image: This is what I have and which have no pattern in cells]

[image: I want this as seen in the table. I highlighted myself to show you what I have and what I want]

Can anybody help me with this thing because I have to do it for thousand of rows and I do it manually until now.

Your quickly help and answers are appreciated.

Comment: How do you identify which numbers to include in column **A**? are they identified because they are numeric values and have a length of **<=** 4? Plus where is **5010** coming from?

Comment: Do you want to highlight the second column if the same value is available in the first column?

Comment: This list is actually coming from SAP which is a product list with name and numbers. The original look like different and as a paragraph which I have shorten to this part.

Comment: Anyway I got the answer. Thanks alot bro!

Answer (score 0):

```
1.Select the cells you want to check if you need to highlight
2. click Home > Conditional Formatting > New Rule
3. Click on Use a formula to determine which cells to format
4. Under Format values where this formula is true, type the formula: =A2=B2
5. Click on "Format"
6. Click on "Fill" and choose the color you want to highlight (yellow?)
```

That's it

Comment: Does my answer helps you?

Comment: Hey Ric! Thanks alot for your answer. Actually I do not want to highlight the values in next column. But anyway I got the answer.